# How to show text and image side by side in Latex

Tags: vertical-alignment, minipage, texworks

Hello I need to use minipage to show text between 2 images  , but it's not showing correctley !!

Can you guys tell me what's the modification I need to add to align all of my component??

```
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
  \begin{sffamily}
  \begin{center}
\begin{figure}[h!]
 \begin{minipage}[t]{3cm}
 \centering \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{univ.png}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{7cm}
  \center{Université Hassan II  }
\center{Faculté des sciences et techniques }
\center{Mohammedia}\\
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{2cm}
\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{fstm.jpg}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can place these elements in a regular line, centering them vertically using `valign=c` (from [`adjustbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox)):

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\includegraphics[width=3cm,valign=c]{example-image-a}\hfill
{\sffamily\begin{tabular}{c}
        Université Hassan II         \\ \\
  Faculté des sciences et techniques \\ \\
            Mohammedia
\end{tabular}}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=3cm,valign=c]{example-image-b}%

\bigskip

More content here\ldots

\end{document}
```